# Which method does the finish return to?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

The question is not about how to use startActivityForResult but about the life cycle relating to the finish () event.

I am developing an app in java, android studio.

I have two activitys, A and B, being A my MainActivity.

When I'm in activity B and I press the back button on android (onBackPressed) ...

```
finish();
```

I need to do some things in activity A.

The onCreate method is not executed since the activity was already created ... which method can I use?

Comment: do stuff in onResume or start Activity B as startActivityForResult and when you press the back button call the setresult method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage startActivityForResult on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is use `onActivityResult(...)` but for that, you need to specify the startActivityForResult value and send the result on the Activity B

```
Intent().also { 
    startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST)
}
```

For more information: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result